# EasyNetQ model shutdown

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, easynetq

I implement a simple client to RabbitMQ, using EasyNetQ. After a connection, I get a notification **"Model shutdown for queue"**. Here is my code:

```
var _bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus(String.Format("host={0}", hostName)).Advanced;
var _exchange = Exchange.DeclareFanout(exName);
var _queue = Queue.DeclareTransient();
_queue.BindTo(_exchange, "_");
_bus.Subscribe(
 _queue,
 (msg, properties, messageReceivedInfo) =>
 {
  return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
   Console.WriteLine(msg.Length.ToString());
  });
 });
```

Using more low-level approach, everything works great (the message length is displayed in the console):

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.HostName = hostName;
var connect = factory.CreateConnection();
var channel = connect.CreateModel();
channel.ExchangeDeclare(exName, "fanout");
var resultQueue = channel.QueueDeclare(string.Empty, false, true, false, null);
string queueName = resultQueue.QueueName;
var consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(channel);
channel.QueueBind(queueName, exName, string.Empty);
var resultConsume = channel.BasicConsume(queueName, false, consumer);
while(true)
{
 var e = (BasicDeliverEventArgs)consumer.Queue.Dequeue();
 Console.WriteLine(e.Body.Length.ToString());
 channel.BasicAck(e.DeliveryTag, false);
}
```

Please, prompt, what's wrong in the first approach?

**UPD**
I caught Exception with IntelliTrace :

> The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by
>   Peer, code=406, text="PRECONDITION_FAILED - cannot redeclare exchange
>   'live' in vhost '/' with different type, durable, internal or
>   autodelete value", classId=40, methodId=10, cause=

Exchange settings are the same (see above). So what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem until I added the parameters that I had already set up when I created the queue via [RabbitMQ Management web interface](http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html), as [Mike Hallow said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15309939/664054).

```
    var arguments = new Dictionary<string, object>( 2 );
    arguments.Add( "x-message-ttl", 900000 );
    arguments.Add( "x-dead-letter-exchange", "deadLetter" );
    this.requestMessageQueue = Queue.Declare( true, false, false, this.messageQueueConfiguration.RequestMessageQueueName, arguments );
```

You can check the existing parameters that are set via the RabbitMQ Management web interface.

---

Since the [recent code change](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/easynetq-big-breaking-changes-in.html), the only way to set arguments directly is through the [Management API](https://github.com/mikehadlow/EasyNetQ/wiki/Queues), unless you are only using per queue ttl (x-message-ttl) or expires (x-expires) in which case you can use the [Advanced API](https://github.com/mikehadlow/EasyNetQ/wiki/The-Advanced-API#declaring-queues).

Answer (score 2):

Are you disposing your _bus soon after doing the subscribe? That would close the subscription channel.

Comment: No, I'm not disposing the **_bus** after subscribing

Comment: I've tried running your example code. I only get "Model Shutdown for queue' when I dispose the _bus, otherwise it works fine.

Comment: I have updated the question. Could you give me any advice now?

Comment: The problem is exactly as described in the error message. You are redeclaring the exchange with different parameters. If you first delete your existing exchange (it might be a good idea to clear everything - all exchanges and queues), it will work fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to remove exchange (or change anything in server-side). Is there any other option? If I'm right I catch this error because of exchange is non-durable

Comment: You can delete exchanges using the C# Client library: http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v3.0.4/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-3.0.4-client-htmldoc/html/type-RabbitMQ.Client.IModel.html#method-M:RabbitMQ.Client.IModel.ExchangeDelete(System.String)

Comment: I need to connect to an existing exchange. I can't remove it because the other subscribers use it too.