# Error sending message to queue

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, easynetq

I'm using EasyNetQ to send a message in a queue of rabbit.

I have a code like this

```
using (var bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("MyConnection"))
{                
       bus.Send("MyCodeName", "MyClass");
}
```

the connection is open when I create the bus, but there is this error when I send the message

The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=406, text="PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-max-priority' for queue ....: received none but current is the value '10' of type 'long'", classId=50, methodId=10, cause=

I setup the queue with x-max-priority: 10.
I have to setup anything else in the connection string?

Comment: what is RabbitHutch ? How about ask the question to the manufacturer of this RabbitHutch ?

Comment: sorry, i've modified the question. RabbitHutch  is a class of easynetq used to connect to rabbit queue

Comment: this probably can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290541/easynetq-model-shutdown

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved without using Send method

[EasyNetQ](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/issues/584)

Infact the send method, tries to create a queue before send message.
I have used the publish method

Comment: All right I'm happy you solved your problem, sounds like a bug in ENQ!

Answer (score 0):

Delete the queue/exchange first and try again.

Don't use 'using' around the bus instance, instead instantiate it once in your application and dispose on quit.